# FVM/Flutter unable to find git on non-administrator account on Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, git

As an administrator, fvm works:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> fvm flutter --version
Flutter 3.7.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c07f788888 (3 days ago) • 2023-02-22 17:52:33 -0600
Engine • revision 0f359063c4
Tools • Dart 2.19.2 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

When I try to run it from my user account though, it does not, even though its obviously in my path:

```
C:\Users\saxto>fvm flutter --version
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
C:\Users\saxto>where.exe git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

[image: [![Screenshot of my PATH environment variable][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfanx.png]

Comment: You've installed flutter on "C:\WINDOWS\system32" which is a bad bad thing. You have to download it then put it in a permission free folder. When you are running as normal user there is not a flutter folder (in those folders you shows) with "flutter\bin\flutter.bat" that receives your commands. So, find on your pc this file "flutter.bat" or "dart.bat" the parent folder of bin folder you found those is your flutter path as Admin or normal User

Comment: Its not installed there, that's just the default directory powershell opens for administrator account.  Flutter is installed in: 

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> where.exe fvm
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\fvm.exe

Comment: Your command seems to be different in portions up and down. However there is not a flutter issue, seems you are under a some Docker or something this Chocolatey confuses you. Take a look also on your environment variables as there are two parts of those, one in common/x system and another one x user.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comments aren't really making sense. I'm not running on Docker.  All of I've done so far is install 'git' and 'fvm' via chocolatey and fvm is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in flutter.  git is actually in the path, but when it is run it produces an error about dubious ownership of a repo:

```
PS C:\Users\saxto\fvm\versions\stable> git rev-parse HEAD
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'C:/Users/saxto/fvm/versions/stable'
'C:/Users/saxto/fvm/versions/stable' is owned by:
        'XXX'
but the current user is:
        'YYY'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

        git config --global --add safe.directory C:/Users/saxto/fvm/versions/stable
```

This can be fixed by running the recommended command in the error message. An issue has been filed here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/121488

Comment: This message happened for me when I've installed a version of flutter as the admin user rather than as the normal user. This causes the installed flutter SDK to be owned by the admin user rather than the your own user causing the error thrown by git. To resolve delete the install version fo the SDK and reinstall it as your user.